# IPad simulator's screen resolution

Tags: ios, ipad, ios-simulator, screen-resolution

I designed my first ipad app.

And when i run it on the simulator resolution is really small. Smaller than really ipad's resolution. Right now i have not ipad, and cant test app on it.

What the problem with resolution?

UPD I connect big display to my macbook. But resolution is still small. I think thats because macbook's display is primary and big monitor is the second. How can i change it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the physical resolution of your screen is lower than the physical resolution of the iPad’s screen. For example my iMac’s screen has 1920 pixels per ~19 inches of width, or roughly 100 pixels per inch. The iPad’s screen density is about 130 ppi, one third higher. If you’re serious about your app, you have to test on the real device anyway. (By the way, if you are simply talking about the window size, that can be changed in the Window menu or using ⌘1–⌘3 shortcuts.)

Comment: i will test on real device in few days =) thnx